# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u201c' in position 69: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, nltk

I'm running following code on python 2.7 nltk 3.2.5
My Code:

```
  import codecs
testing = codecs.open("Desktop/sample.txt",'r', 'utf-8').read()
sentences = sent_tokenize(testing)
labeled_sentence = ([(name, "question") for name in sent_tokenize(q)] +[(name, "notquestion") for name in sent_tokenize(i)])
random.shuffle(labeled_sentence)
feature_sets = [(get_features(n), label) for (n, label) in labeled_sentence]
train_set, test_set = feature_sets[500:], feature_sets[:500]
#print(test_set)
classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set)

for sent in sentences:
    print(str(sent) + "" + str(classifier.classify(get_features(sent))))
```

I'm getting following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-c12d2b078e87> in <module>()
     13 #nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier, test_set)
     14 for sent in sentences:
---> 15     print(str(sent) + "" + str(classifier.classify(get_features(sent))))

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u201c' in position 69: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Please help

Comment: If you can, upgrade to python3. Python3 is designed to handle unicode and character conversion natively. YOu can do most thing in python2, but very error prone. In Python2, you should use the prefix `u` before literal strings, and you should use `unicode()` instead of `str()`. So you see the problems with python2 (and most of non unicode-native-designed languages.

Comment: https://pythonclock.org/